# Python interface asserting member variables are defined

Tags: python, class, exception, architecture, member

I try to implement an interface in Python 3.6 (I know they don't exist in Python). Using the following minimal example:

```
import time

class ModuleInterface:
    # How often the module information is updated (int in seconds).
    interval = None
    def update(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class HardDisk(ModuleInterface):
###############################################################################
     pass # First
###############################################################################
#     def update(self):        # Second
#         time.sleep(self.interval) # Second
###############################################################################

hd = HardDisk()
hd.update()
```

The code should yield a NotImplementedError for the first case. In the second case I would like to get a similar error but I don't know how to implement this correctly in Python. The idea of an interface is to yield an error if something is not defined. But interval is defined, which is why the second case will yield a TypeError. This is however not the kind of error I'd like to get. It would be perfect to assert for all members of the ModuleInterface that they must be defined by the inheriting class.

Comment: Why don't you try using ABC module in `python`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the correct module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html). Exemple (Python 2.7 - you'll find py3 exemples in [the 3.6 doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/abc.html)):

```
import abc
import time

class ModuleInterface(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    # How often the module information is updated (int in seconds).
    interval = abc.abstractproperty()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def update(self):
        """ must be implemented """

class WrongHardDisk(ModuleInterface):
    """ This one doesn't define `interval` 
        so it cannot be instanciated 
    """
    def update(self):
        time.sleep(self.interval)


class HardDisk(ModuleInterface):
    interval = 5
    def update(self):
        time.sleep(self.interval)

try:
    # Will raise a TypeError
    whd = WrongHardDisk()
except Exception as e:
    print type(e), e

# this one will work as expected
hd = HardDisk()
hd.update()
```

AFAICT the only modification to make it work with Python 3.6 should be to replace this (untested):

```
class ModuleInterface(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    # ...
```

with

```
class ModuleInterface(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you, your code definitely points me into the correct direction. I still try to figure out how to use abc in Python 3.6... The thing is I don't get the TypeError you mentioned. There is no error when instanciating the wrong hard disc.

Comment: The error is catched and printed to stdout. If you want to see it happen try instanciating `WrongHardDisk` outside a try/except block.

Comment: wrt/ "how to use abc in Python 3.6." I edited my post (caveat: untested).

Comment: Thank you for your post and the comments. The error did indeed not occur (also without try-except). But your suggestion "class ModuleInterface(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):" did the trick for Python 3.6. Thanks a lot for this great example and have a nice day!